# Access elements created with UI builder in xcode with Objective C by title or ID

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I have looked everywhere and I cant seem to figure out how to access elements in my UI in xcode. I know how to change and access elements when I create the UI elements programmatically, but not when I make them using the xcode ui builder.

Simply put: Is there a get element by title or something similar (I do not see ID attributes) and if its there please tell me where it is or how to set it.

Javascript equivalent of what i am trying to do: `document.getElementById('ID');`

Java equivalent of what i am trying to do: `(EditText)findViewById(ID);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get an element by its tag. If you are in a view controller code and you need to get a button that you tagged as `123` in the interface builder, you can use this code:

```
UIButton *button123 = [self.view viewWithTag:123];
```

The element does not need to be a button - it can be any `UIView` descendant: a label, a text view, a stepper, or anything else.

Please note that a more idiomatic way of accessing elements that you create in the interface builder is through `IBOutlet`s.

Here is how you can add an outlet to your view or view controller: open interface builder in a separate window, control-click the element that you want to add as an outlet, find "referencing outlet/new referencing outlet" in the context menu that drops down, and drag from the black circle into the header of your view or view controller. When you drop the item into the code, you will be prompted for the name of the outlet. Once the outlet is created, you can access its corresponding element through the variable that you created.

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman You are welcome! Please take a look at the edit: although you can always access elements by their tags, outlets provide a much more convenient way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: I was just about to ask you about that! Thanks, now that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: How does one give an element a tag in interface builder? I see no such property.

Comment: @chaiguy It's in the "View" section of the Attribute Inspector. You may need to click the triangle to make sure that the section is open and visible.

Comment: How do you know if the tag is unique? This seems really poorly thought out. lol

Comment: @EzekielVictor I don't fully understand your question: are you asking how do you know that the tags assigned by you are unique?

Comment: Tags are being used as identifying, yet AFAICT there is nothing stopping one from (mistakenly, for example) using the same tag for multiple controls. It's not so hard to fathom happening in a project with multiple developers.

Comment: You can only use numbers and not text to tag a control?

Comment: @MatthewLock Correct.